# Conceptual Understanding of a Simple Random Process

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, random-variables, random

I have a simple discrete time random process that with probability $0.5$ chooses a deterministic sequence so that $X(t) = -1$, for $t<1$ and $X(t) = +1$ for $t \geq 1$, similarly with probability $0.5$ it chooses the deterministic sequence that is the negative of this, so $X(t) = +1$ for $t<1$ and $X(t) = -1$ for $t\geq 1$. Obviously the ensemble of this process is these 2 fixed sequences.

My problem is thinking about sampling this random process, say at times $t=1$, and $t=3$. If I sample $X(1)=+1$, does that mean $X(3)$ also must be $+1$, I was thinking no? Basically I'm trying to understand if this process is at all statistically different from one made of a sequence of bernoulli RV's that chose $\pm 1$ with equiprobability of $1/2$.

Comment: Looks the same to me.

Comment: These are quite different processes. For example, considering i.i.d. Bernoulli random variables $(Y_t)$, $$P(Y_2=1,Y_3=-1)=\tfrac14\ne0=P(X_2=1,X_3=-1).$$

Comment: Did thank you that makes sense. So for this process we would have P(Xk=+1)=P(Xk=−1)=0.5 for all k like we have in the bernoulli however we would also have P(X0=−1,X1=+1)=P(X0=+1,X1=−1)=0.5 which is quite distinct from the bernoulli case